# python igraph - get_adjlist() not returning vertex names, only ids

Tags: python, igraph

I'm loading a graphml into igraph

```
from igraph import *
wiki = Graph.Read_GraphML("discussion_network.graphml")
```

but when I do

```
g = wiki.get_adjlist()
```

I get id's, while in the graphml file there are actually stored names for every node.

```
>>> g = wiki.get_adjlist()
>>> str(g[0])
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
>>> str(g[1])
'[0, 2, 3097, 3099, 3101, 3102, 3103, 3106]'
>>>
```

How Can I create a list with names, not ids ?

```
>>> summary(wiki)
IGRAPH UNW- 17266 116036 --
+ attr: id (v), name (v), weight (e)
```

Thanks.

**Update:**

I'm manually adding names to a collection with code `wiki.vs.find(i)['name']` executed in a loop, but I'm looking forward for some more civilized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a utility function and then use it whenever you need an adjacency list with names:

```
def get_adjlist_with_names(graph):
    names = graph.vs["name"]
    result = {}
    for index, neighbors in enumerate(graph.get_adjlist()):
        result[names[index]] = [names[nei] for nei in neighbors]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in python-igraph package.

I'm looking forward to close question when possible.